# How can I separate my app with react admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have my application that works with a hash router with routes like "login" "register" "dashboard" and I would like to integrate react-admin. I would like to use react admin on my /admin route.

What I do:

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {HashRouter  as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import Store from './store/configureStore'
import RegisterView from "./view/RegisterView"
import LoginView from "./view/LoginView"
import DashboardView from "./view/DashboardView"

import AdminView from "./view/AdminView"
import jsonServerProvider from "ra-data-json-server";
import { Admin, Resource, BooleanField } from "react-admin";
import { UserList, UserEdit, UserCreate } from './users';


const dataProvider =
    jsonServerProvider("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com");

class App extends Component {
  // Provider store is used to use the store of the redux
    // Router is used to define the route and the component to display

  render() {

    return (
        <div>
          <Provider store={Store}>
            <Router basename="/">
              <div>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={LoginView}>
                  </Route>
                  <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterView}>
                  </Route>
                  <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginView}>
                  </Route>
                  <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={DashboardView}>
                  <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminView}>
                      <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
                          <Resource
                              name="users"
                              list={UserList}
                              edit={UserEdit}
                              create={UserCreate}
                          />
                      </Admin>
                  </Route>
              </div>
            </Router>
          </Provider>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

it displays my react-admin but with my other components (display bug). I would like the react-admin part only in my /admin routes.

For me, the  section should only be working in the /admin because i gave this path to my route.

What don't I understand?

Comment: Did you read the documentation about Including (React Admin) in Another App? https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CustomApp.html